# how to insert buttons on the west side an Image file on the East Side or simply as a background using Tk

Tags: python-2.7, canvas, tkinter

Here is my script

```
# Python 2.7.14 version

from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox
from urllib2 import urlopen
import PIL
from PIL import ImageTk
import ImageTk

FILENAME = 'Fleur_de_lys.jpg'
root = Tk()
background = Canvas(root, width=250, height=250)##AttributeError: class Tk has no attribute 'Canvas'
canvas.pack()
tk_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage( file = FILENAME)
canvas.create_image(125, 125, image=tk_img)
quit_button = tk.Button(root, text = "Quit", command = root.quit, anchor = 'w',
                    width = 10, activebackground = "#33B5E5")
quit_button_window = canvas.create_window(10, 10, anchor='nw', window=quit_button)
root.mainloop()
```

No matter what attempt I do I keep getting AttributeError: class Tk has no attribute 'Canvas' where is my error if I just create button I have no issue what so ever all work but when I attempt to have a background image everything does not work

Comment: the code you posted will not give the error `class Tk has no attribute 'Canvas'`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that you're creating a canvas, and storing it in a variable named `background`, yet the very next line you are trying to call something called 'canvas', which you've never created.

Change this:

```
background = Canvas(root, width=250, height=250)
canvas.pack()
...
canvas.create_image(125, 125, image=tk_img)
```

to this:

```
background = Canvas(root, width=250, height=250)
background.pack()
...
background.create_image(125, 125, image=tk_img)
```

Comment: Will try doing this and work with what was suggested it seems I still have the same problem for some reason it says now that the image does not exist but yet I see in the folder. I will figure what I am doing wrong probably a space or quotes. Thanks answering total new guy doing this kind of programming

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue jpg image was not being accepted I made it with a gif. Also found how to correct the buttons location and posn.

```
Here is the example without all the program

canvas = Canvas(root, width = 500, height = 500, bg='black')
canvas.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
my_image =  PhotoImage(file='C:\\MOTD\\fleur_de_lys.gif')
canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor = NW, image=my_image)

b1 = Button(root, text="From the Commander", command=callback,anchor = 'w',
            width = 18, activebackground = "#33B5E5")
button_window1 = canvas.create_window(10, 10, anchor='nw', window=b1)
```